# Calculator cannot be opened using the built-in administrator account

Tags: windows-10

I've tried all the steps in other posts and still no luck. I have UAC set to never, I'm logged in as admin, policy UAC: admin approval mode for admins is set to enable.

I know calc.exe is a huge security risk but is there anyway to run it without UAC?

Comment: Calc shouldn't require Admin permissions or a UAC approval to open. You sure your Calc.exe is legitimate?

Comment: How is using the built in calculator (calc.exe) a huge security risk?

Comment: I have noticed that there are similar restrictions on the built-in `Administrator` account on a Windows 10 machine.  For example, you can't open the default Photos app with the `Administrator` account.  That being said, it is typically a security best-practice to avoid using the built-in Administrator account, leaving it disabled and creating additional admin-level local accounts instead.  Is there a compelling reason why you need to use the `Administrator` account?

Comment: Windows 10 Built-in Administrator account is unable to open ANY Metro Apps. And unfortunately in Windows 10 Calculator is a Metro App.

Comment: An alternate to calc.exe and maybe a step up is googol, it's now Free and has more power. http://www.atelierweb.com/products/googol/ There are  even more steps up from googol, but use what works best for you.

Comment: @JoshCampbell Sarcasm :)

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Fresh MSDN install

Comment: @Run5k Understandable but this isn't a mission critical machine so there should be no reason to create several accounts. Like saying I should have a 64 character password on my digital diary :)

Comment: It's unfortunate that the proposed solution in Michael Pietroforte's article didn't work, but it did help shed some light on the subject.  That being said, if you don't mind me asking is there really a compelling reason to use the built-in `Administrator` account?  You don't need to create several local admin accounts to alleviate this problem... just one.

Comment: @Run5k Other than I'd have to re-setup all my settings, desktop, etc. not really. So just using another admin account, just not the built-in one bypasses this issue? EDIT: Just checked and I'm using the account made during setup not the "Administrator" account.

Comment: Yes, absolutely… I utilize that configuration on a daily basis with the local admin account that I created when Windows 10 was first installed.  Like the article said, *"The built-in administrator account essentially runs with all UAC settings disabled."*  In contrast, a locally created admin account doesn't, so it doesn't have any problems running Photos, Calculator, etc.  **EDIT**:  if that's the case, you may want to modify your question.  That makes a world of difference!  That being said, are you sure that you don't have UAC completely disabled?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an excellent article that helps explain the problem:

[Why the built-in administrator account can’t open Edge (and a lesson in UAC)](https://4sysops.com/archives/why-the-built-in-administrator-account-cant-open-edge-and-a-lesson-in-uac/).

Ultimately, the author emphasizes the following:

> The built-in administrator account essentially runs with all UAC settings disabled. ... By default, the built-in administrator cannot execute modern apps.

As a result, your built-in `Administrator` account will see messages like the following:

[image: Edge Error Message]

The author goes on to explain that you should be able to mitigate this problem by navigating to the following Group Policy location:

```
Computer Configuration > Policies > Windows Settings > Security > Security Options
```

Then, enable the following policy:

```
User Account Control: Admin Approval Mode for the Built-in Administrator account
```

If this isn't the built-in `Administrator` account and merely a locally created admin account experiencing the same issues, you may have inadvertently disabled UAC entirely.  Once again, quoting the article:

> Actually, if you completely disable UAC, no one will be able to run these colorful toy applications. Note that you can’t completely disable UAC through the Control Panel. With the setting **Never notify**, UAC is still active.
>
> To turn off all UAC settings, you have to **disable** the security policy **User Account Control: Run all administrators in Admin Approval Mode (Computer Configuration > Policies > Windows Settings > Security > Security Options)**.

If that happened through either a Group Policy or registry change, you should be able to reverse that rather easily to restore access to the modern apps.

Comment: I've tried these and still get the same message.

Comment: I just updated this answer with additional text from the referenced article that explains how this could potentially be happening to a locally created admin account.

Comment: that did the trick! I must have disabled that setting while going through articles. Thanks again for all your help!

Comment: With the countless number of Group Policies and registry options at our disposal, that type of thing can happen to the best of us.  It is good to hear that your account is back to normal, and I'm always glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

I do not see this mentioned here but this was the actual fix for my MS Windows 10 enterprise "Calculator cannot be opened using the built-in administrator account". I have been fighting this for weeks, trying everything I have read on the internet without any solution. The final fix was so simple.
logged into the admin account, went to uac settings, changed it to the highest level, tested calculator, of coarse it did not work and came up with the same error, then I went back into the uac settings and set it to the lowest setting, tested calculator and it still did not work, but it is not supposed to in the administrator account. I rebooted the computer and logged back into the administrator account (accidentally), then logged out and logged into my account which is also an administrator account, I tested calculator and it works now. I hope this helps somebody, I was so frustrated. My main reason for wanting to change this setting is that I have an HP envy 4520 printer that never completes the software setting. it was freezing when it would try and start the web browser. I tried it in a non admin account and it would complete the setup but would not setup the correct drivers because the drivers were locked from it not being an admin account. Now I am off to try and install the printer again now that the uac problem has been fixed.

A quick note: Something about being in the actual administrator account and changing the UAC setting from low to high saving the setting, then changing it from high to low seems to fix the broken UAC. The actual changes will not work until the system is rebooted, and not just logged off.